# How to retrieve data from a logfile where timestamp can be followed by multiline log

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, logs

I have a logfile that I am trying to 'grep' data out of via a bash script. The data I am specifically after is all lines between two timestamps (including the top timestamp) that have the pattern "ERR-" and include an empty line after each entry for readability.

example logfile:

```
Tue May 24 21:22:12 2022
ERR-0045 Lock detected in /tmp/file.lck
Tue May 24 21:44:12 2022
Errors in file /tmp/filename01.trc:
ERR-0001: Error detected. /tmp/filename.log
Tue May 24 21:47:25 2022
im some output
Tue May 24 21:47:25 2022
im some output too
im some output aswell
Tue May 24 21:48:03 2022
Errors in file /tmp/filename09.trc:
ERR-0100: error
ERR-0050: failure of sorts.
ERR-0052: line 3421
Tue May 24 21:49:07 2022
Completed process xyz
```

So my desired output would look like :

```
Tue May 24 21:22:12 2022
ERR-0045 Lock detected in /tmp/file.lck
    
Tue May 24 21:44:12 2022
Errors in file /tmp/filename01.trc:
ERR-0001: Error detected. /tmp/filename.log
        
Tue May 24 21:48:03 2022
Errors in file /tmp/filename09.trc:
ERR-0100: error
ERR-0050: failure of sorts.
ERR-0052: line 3421
```

I have tried using combinations of sed/awk/cat without much success. Where I am having trouble is:

1. It's not always two lines before ERR- which contains the timestamp
2. There can be multiple ERR-'s in one timestamp block
3. The date will obviously change so i don't want to hard code that in, although the format won't change.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Script `tst.awk`:

```
function print_r() { if (e) print r; r = ""; e = 0 }

/^([[:alpha:]]{3} ){2}[[:digit:]]{1,2} [[:digit:]]{2}(:[[:digit:]]{2}){2} [[:digit:]]{4}$/ {
    print_r()
}
/^ERR-/{ e = 1 }
{ r = r ORS $0 }
END{ print_r() }
```

Usage and output:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file

Tue May 24 21:22:12 2022
ERR-0045 Lock detected in /tmp/file.lck

Tue May 24 21:44:12 2022
Errors in file /tmp/filename01.trc:
ERR-0001: Error detected. /tmp/filename.log

Tue May 24 21:48:03 2022
Errors in file /tmp/filename09.trc:
ERR-0100: error
ERR-0050: failure of sorts.
ERR-0052: line 3421
```

You can use your own expressions for the timestamp or the error. Here is a whole line matching of the presented format (no date validation). And "ERR-" at the beginning of a line.

---

**Notes:**

- We define a function to print a record (`r`) if error found (`e`). Also to reset both variables after printing. For `awk`, variables that have not been initialised with a value are evaluated to the empty string or zero.
- When the regular expression for the date is matched, we call this function. To finish about previous log record and to start holding the new record. Because the record is a multiline log, we don't know yet if we have to print it or not.
- When the error pattern is matching, we set `e`.
- For every row, we append the row to the existing record, separated by the `ORS`, the output record separator, default newline. Also, the empty line between output lines is placed at the beginning of `r`, `r` is always the empty string when we are here for a new timestamp.
- At the `END` we call the function again, because the last record is still held.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted and it works perfectly with my "real data". I certainly don't understand the code - would you mind giving a pseudo code explanation of what it does? If not that is okay too - thank you so much.

Comment: I have updated with some notes, welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```bash
~$ raku -e 'my @a=slurp; @a.=split(/ <?after ^^ ERR \V* > \n <?before ^^ Tue > /); \
            put $_.subst(/^ <(.+)> ^^ Tue/) ~ "\n" if /^^ ERR / for @a;'   file
```

The problem seems to be that you have some timestamped records with `ERR` lines and some without, and you'd like to discard the latter.

Above, the file is `slurp`ed into `@a` array. Then `@a` is `split` on `\n` between records `<?after  ^^ ERR \V* >` ending with a line that starts with `ERR` followed by zero-or-more `\V` non-vertical whitespace characters, and `<?before ^^ Tue >` before a line starting with `Tue`.

In the second statement out`put(…)` is refined. The `@a` elements are individually (and automatically) represented by `$_` in the preamble to the `for` clause. Each element is `if /^^ ERR/` conditionally-tested to make sure they contain a line starting with `ERR`: `if` so, the `$_` element is `$_.subst(/^ <(.+)> ^^ Tue/)` substituted removing all leading characters before an *internal* start-of-line `Tue`. Essentially here, `.subst` without a replacement means to delete the match between `<(`…`)>` capture markers. To separate individual records, `$_.subst(…) ~ "\n"` elements are `~` tilde concatenated with a record-separating `"\n"` newline.

Sample Input:

```
Tue May 24 21:22:12 2022
ERR-0045 Lock detected in /tmp/file.lck
Tue May 24 21:44:12 2022
Errors in file /tmp/filename01.trc:
ERR-0001: Error detected. /tmp/filename.log
Tue May 24 21:47:25 2022
im some output
Tue May 24 21:47:25 2022
im some output too
im some output aswell
Tue May 24 21:48:03 2022
Errors in file /tmp/filename09.trc:
ERR-0100: error
ERR-0050: failure of sorts.
ERR-0052: line 3421
Tue May 24 21:49:07 2022
Completed process xyz
```

Sample Output:

```
Tue May 24 21:22:12 2022
ERR-0045 Lock detected in /tmp/file.lck

Tue May 24 21:44:12 2022
Errors in file /tmp/filename01.trc:
ERR-0001: Error detected. /tmp/filename.log

Tue May 24 21:48:03 2022
Errors in file /tmp/filename09.trc:
ERR-0100: error
ERR-0050: failure of sorts.
ERR-0052: line 3421
```

Certainly, the above is a bare bones implementation (it's meant to be--for readability). To work on dates starting on other days of the week, substitute `Tues` above with the following:

```perl
 [ Mon || Tue || Wed || Thu || Fri || Sat || Sun ]
```

(It should be obvious from the code above how to add months to your regex, should you run into problems with specificity).

https://raku.org